# Find $\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y}$ in a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ be mutually independent random variables.

Each $X_i$ in the sequence $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ has the normal distribution $X_i$~$N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$ and is idnependent random variable and we have each $Y_j$ in the sequence $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m$ has the normal distribution $Y_J$~$N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$ and is independent random variable for some $\mu \in$R and

$\sigma_1^2>0$ and $\sigma_2^2>0$

$\tilde{X}=n^{-1}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$ and we Have $\tilde{Y}=(m)^{-1}(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_m)$

And $Z:=(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$

A. FIND THE probability distribution of $\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y}$

So I know both $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ have a normal distribution.

So I think $E(\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y})$ would be $U(n)+U(m)$ but
I am not sure how you would find $var(\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are sample averages constructed from i.i.d. observations, so $\tilde{X}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2_1}{n}\right)$ and $\tilde{Y}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2_2}{m}\right)$. The sum of independent normal random variables is normal, so $\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y}$ is normal with mean $2\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2_1}{n}+\frac{\sigma^2_2}{m}$.